# Display a message when a document is being printed

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and my mentor wanted me to do a program that would show a message stating that a document is being printed.

I already tried searching the internet and found nothing.

If you know anything, please help me.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what kind of c# application you are making? As in, which framework will you be using? WinForms, WPF, etc.

Comment: im using in WinForms

Answer (score 1):

> You say you searched on Google but you did not find anything

But the truth is that the documentation is there, you just have to search correctly

[`PrintDocument.Print Method()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.print%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> The following code is illustrative, it does not intend to do your work, but to guide you in what you want to do

```
 using System.Drawing.Printing; //For PrintDocument
 using System.Windows.Forms //For MessageBox

 public class PrintingExample 
 {
    private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Printing");
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
       PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument(); 
       pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
       //Print the document.
       pd.Print(); 
    }
 }
```

> As you see, you need to use the `PrintPage` event of `PrintDocument`, which is executed when you give the print order

```
pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
```

> This, in turn, calls the `pd_PrintPage()` method, which in turn displays the message

```
private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Printing");
}
```